# Symfony2 Use Doctrine in Service Container

Tags: doctrine, symfony

How do I use Doctrine in a service container?

The Code just causes an error message "Fatal error: Call to undefined method ...::get()".

```
<?php

namespace ...\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use ...\Entity\Header;

class dsdsf
{ 
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $id = 10;
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $em->getRepository('...')->find($id);
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
service:
    site:
        class: ...\Service\Site
```

Answer (score 85):

According to your code, you already have an `EntityManager` injected. You don't need to call `$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()` — just use `$this->em`.

If you don't inject an `EntityManager` already, read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#service-parameters).

UPDATE:

You need to make the container inject an `EntityManager` into your service. Here's an example of doing it in `config.yml`:

```
services:
    your.service:
        class: YourVendor\YourBundle\Service\YourService
        arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager ]
```

I prefer to [define](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#configuring-services-and-setting-parameters) bundles' services in their own `services.yml` files, but that's a bit more advanced, so using `config.yml` is good enough to get started.

Comment: Do you mean like this?

$this->em->getRepository('...')->find($id);

"atchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given"

Comment: Yes, I meant that. You're getting this error because you're not injecting an EntityManager from the container. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @user1075510: If this is the best answer, please checkmark it.

Comment: Can we also pass in `arguments: [@doctrine]` and just call `$this->doctrine->getEntityManager()` ? I seem to be getting a "A new entity was found through the relationship" error whenever I pass in doctrine.orm.entity_manager, but it gets resolved whenever I use the latter

Comment: It's also better to pass Doctrine and call getEntityManager every single time because the entity manager gets closed after Database Level Errors. So if you want to manually do stuff after a known transaction failure, your screwed.

Comment: or [ @doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager ] its the same thing :)

Answer (score 10):

For easily accessing the Entitymanager use the following one:

```
//services.yml
  your service here:
    class: yourclasshere
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

And in the class itself:

```
class foo
{
  protected $em;



  public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function bar()
  {
      //Do the Database stuff
      $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();

      //Your Query goes here

      $result = $query->getResult();
  }
}
```

This is my first answer so any comments are appreciated :)

Comment: The example class that you posted isn't valid PHP. Correct your example, and I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: You missed 2 semi colons

Comment: You cannot call any functions outside of a method scope (e.g. right in the class). Calling `$this->em->createQueryBuilder()` would never work, because referring to `$this` is invalid at this point.

Comment: little typo `protected $em:` should be `protected $em;`

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code:

```
 $em=$this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();

 $rolescheduels=$em->getRepository('OCSOCSBundle:RoleScheduel')->findByUser($user->getId());
```

Answer (score 3):

### For Symfony 3.x

The most easy-peasy solution for me was to just turn on autowiring/autoconfiguring, and then injecting the service I needed via the constructor. Note that I have also allowed any controller to be injected as a service by setting **`resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'`**

```
 #services.yml or config.yml
 services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false
    # Allow any controller to be used as a service
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'    
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests,DataFixtures,Form}'
```

Then in any service, you can inject & use the entity manager `$em` (or any other **service/controller**) via the constructor like this:

```
// class xyz
private $em;
// constructor
public function __construct(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em)  {
    $this->em = $em;
}
public function bar() {
    //Do the Database stuff
    $query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    //Your Query goes here
    $result = $query->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for anyone who works with symfony3: u need to do the following inside config/services.yml in order to use doctrine in Service Container:

```
servicename_manager:
          class: AppBundle\Services\MyServiceClass
          arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

in the **Symfony 3.4.** If you want to use Doctrine in a service you can do it:
Only this method worked for me

**services.yml**:

```
YourBundle\PatchService\YourService:
      public: true
      arguments: [ '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' ]
```

**Service**:

```
class YourService
{
    private $em;
    public function __construct($em)  {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
```

**Controller**:

```
use YourBundle\PatchService\YourService;

     /**
         * @Route("/YourController/",name="YourController")
         */
        public function indexAction()
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $Notification = new  YourService($em);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Symfony 3.4. If you want to create a service in a bundle this works for me:

```
services:
 Vendor\YourBundle\Service\YourService:
   arguments:
     $em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
```

In your Service.php

```
<?php

namespace Hannoma\ElternsprechtagBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Hannoma\ElternsprechtagBundle\Entity\Time;

class TimeManager
{
 protected $em;

 public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
 {
    $this->em = $em;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2017 and Symfony 3.3** you can **register Repository as service**, with all its advantages it has.

Your code would change like this.

#### 1. Service configuration

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    ...\Service\:
       resource: ...\Service
```

#### 2. Create new class - **custom repository**:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class YourRepository
{ 
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(YourEntity::class);
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->repository->find($id);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Use in any Controller or Service like this

```
class dsdsf
{ 
    private $yourRepository;

    public function __construct(YourRepository $yourRepository)
    {
        $this->yourRepository = $yourRepository;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $id = 10;
        $this->yourRepository->find($id);
    }
}
```

---

Do you want to see more code and pros/cons lists?

**Check my post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)**.

Comment: Why not define it in your service config as an argument? `@=service("doctrine.orm.entity_manager").getRepository("Namespace\Entity")`

Comment: Framework-agnostic PHP code over framework-coupled-config-yaml-specific knowledge.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you. Sorry, I should have provided a link to the [Symfony expression usage](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html)