# Symfony 3 - Access to Doctrine from Service

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm

Can you suggest me a solution, how to get access to Doctrine from a Service in Symfony 3?
I send an object of Doctrine from Controller to created Service object in a constructor but I not sure if it is the best option.

Could you recommend me a better solution?

```
 public function editGroupAction($groupId) {
   $doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();
   $roleHelper = new RoleHelper($doctrine);
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? One of the main requirements on SO is to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Helenesh I added an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 Use Doctrine in Service Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342031/symfony2-use-doctrine-in-service-container/45269646#45269646)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inject it like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
    $this->em = $entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer